# Парсинг ячеек SQLite из файла

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, парсер

Здравствуйте, я хочу извлечь все значения из SQLite3 базы данных, не используя библиотеку SQLite. Никак не могу понять, как разбить строку на ячейки(все данные записаны слитно). Есть предположение, что эти данные содержатся в ключе строки, но как его разобрать не знаю. Хотелось бы узнать, как же все таки распарсить базу.

Например, я создал базу данных с 2-мя столбцами формата TEXT.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно извлечь эти данные из таблицы, не используя библиотеку SQLite(т.е. не запросом, а напрямую из файла).
В HxD эта база выглядит так(указатель на страницу и данные в ней я нашел, как узнать, а вот каким образом разделять ячейки нет, так как они просто слитно записаны).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В исходнике sqlite смотрел, но что-то там сложно все понять(может быть потому что запросы более сложные операции выполняют чем просто чтение данных из файла).

Comment: Читать исходный код библиотеки не пробовали?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Пробовал, но больно труднопонимаемо там все. Завтра подробнее суть опишу.